# My book says this program would have the loop run indefinitely but the compiler does it just for a limited number of times

Tags: c

Here is the program using a while loop,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int i;
   i = 1;
   while (i <= 32767)
   {
       printf("%d", i);
       i = i + 1;
   }
}
```

do you think the loop would execute indefinitely?

Comment: Very likely yes -- and if you have **compiler warnings enabled** -- the compiler will tell you why...

Comment: "My book": [edit] its title, authors, and year of publication into your question. If it's something like "Turbo-C For Kids, (c) 1982" then you need a more recent tutorial.

Comment: usr2564301 don't mock me dude its my text book thats not bearing any standard commercial author or edition or is renowned, I'm a kid though

Comment: We're not mocking you; we're trying to find out whether it is sensible for you to be using that text book.  It may not be if it thinks `sizeof(int) == 2`.  It is no longer a common compiler configuration for the non-embedded systems you are probably using while you learn C.  (Further, it hasn't been common since the mid-90s, if not earlier — which is long before you were born if you're still a kid.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler
sadly just because of the comment you made I just stumbled upon the sizeof unary operator on wiki and realized that I forgot over 15 pages of chapter 1 of my book and now I'm back to square 1....:(
I study chapters and then I realize that I've forgotten the past pages and go back and so on this process has halted my learning quite seriously.

Comment: There are, sadly, a lot of bad books on C which should not be used for learning modern C.  They were usually of indifferent quality when written, but the passage of time and changes to the C language make them counter-productive now.  There's a [Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) that covers most of the better books — there are bound to be omissions, but it is still some help.  If your book is not on the list, then be cautious.  This question indicates that you need to be cautious with it.

Comment: Johnathanleffler my book is listed as a keep away from

Comment: Just to mention, many answers/comments made here are solely for the purpose of gaining reputation points, since no further responses are given

Comment: Do you mean you need more answers? It seems to me all bases are covered, and there is enough choice for you to pick one and [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.

Comment: My account has already been slaughtered by the SO bots...nvm...
Btw usr2564301 dude you talk too much but don't even put a name on...not a standard practice...just saying

Answer (score 5):

Well it's signed integer. Considering that if `int` is of 16 bits, it will overflow at one point precisely when the value is `INT_MAX` or `32767`. At that point it is undefined behavior.

It is ***undefined behavior*** - when `int` is of 16 bits. As the behavior is undefined we can't say it will always run  infinitely etc in that case.

> In your system if `int` is of **`32` bits or higher** then the behavior of this program is **not**
>   undefined.

From [**standard**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1)

> .... **Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or
>   greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same
>   sign**.

In your case if `sizeof(int) = 4` or higher, then the loop will stop. The only way to know whether the behavior is undefined or not is  to know what the size of `int` is.

#### To summarise

- If `int` is of 32 bits or higher then this will stop.
- If `int` is of 16 bits then this will be undefined behavior. It may loop indefinitely or it may not. It's not defined by the standard.

Comment: why would it overflow when the while loop has demanded the loop to stop right at 32767?

Comment: @Simon.: Check the answer it might help

Comment: `7fff -> 8000 -> ... -> 7fff -> 8000 -> ...` yes it may be implementation defined, but it will likely run forever given `(i <= 32767) -- "is always true due to limited range of data type"`. (test it with `char i` and `(i <= 127)` and a counter to break after `127` reached twice)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin.: Yes if it becomes negative then yes it will run for ever (and follows the same policy each time 32767 is incremented on that variable type)//but yes if it is `8000` or something  then it will stop. (Both are covered by that undefined behavior that the standard says about)

Comment: No argument over the undefined nature of adding 1 to `INT_MAX`, but it was kindof a neat question.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin.: My earlier edit was missing the size argument. ( Yes it is a quick edit and all that ) and I mentioend teacher instead of book. But well that fetched me a DV.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin.: Thanks for the comment and stopping by.

Comment: @coderredoc I don't know who the dv voter was, but obviously they didn't have the integrity to back up their downvote with a comment. Those all come out in the wash anyway...

Comment: @Simon: The code does not say “Stop at 32767.” It says “Continue if `i` <= 32767.” In order for that test to be false, `i` must first be incremented to be more than 32767. If `int` cannot represent 32768, that is not possible, and incrementing `i` beyond 32767 has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

If you disregard the specific numbers and instead write

```
while (i <= MAX_INT)
```

the compiler sees this as *"loop while `i` is less than or equal to the largest value it can ever have"*.

As `i` - by definition - can never be larger than the largest value, this condition will always be true and the loop would be infinite.

However, as the code tries to compute `i + 1` even when `i` cannot possibly become any larger, there is an error in the program. The language standard explicltly states that if the program tries this - overflow on a signed variable - the result is undefined.

Undefined behavior can have *any* result according to the language standard. This includes getting some other value for `i` (perhaps a negative one despite trying to add 1), having the OS trap and terminate the program, or *possibly* even terminate a loop that would otherwise be infinite. We just don't know.

Comment: why is the initialization always by 1 and not zero?
it always starts with i = 1; but not i = 0;
why so ??

Comment: @Simon - The 1 is just an example, it could be *any* value. But you have to give it *some* value, otherwise all uses of `i` would be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your book. And in fact the book is correct if you assume that the type `int` is a 16 bit signed integer. The range of a 16 bit integer goes from -32768 to +32767. So in this case the condition `i<=32767` will always be true.

But in your programm I think the type of `int` is a 32 bit integer which range goes from -2147483648 to +2147483647.

If you replace `int i` with `short i` the loop should be an infinity loop.

Comment: even if it goes upto 32767,  with a 16bit int should'nt it just stop right there and not go beyond the int limit of 32767 as mentioned in the while loop ? why would it be indefinite?

Comment: @Simon: Your condition is that the loop should run if `i` is smaller or equal to 32767. The max value for `i` (if it's a 16 bit signed integer) is 32767. So the condition is true. The next value (after `i = i + 1`) is -32768 (because of a integer overflow) and the condiition is still true.

Comment: why the next value after 32767 is -32768? why the negative sign? the range is -32768 to 32767....

Comment: After the variable 'i' reaches 32767, a new iteration of the loop is executed. Then, 'i' will be incremented and overflow. So this leads to undefined behavior, not necessarily infinite loop.

Comment: 32767 is the same as 0x7FFF. The next value is 0x8000 which represents -32768 (for a singed integer). And this is called a integer overflow.

Comment: The C standard does not define the behavior on integer overflow. Arithmetic cannot be relied upon to wrap. A program may wrap, abort, get wrong results, or behave in any other way.